# How to customize a column chart in html

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Currently i am using chart.js   but not able to make chart like following

[image]

in which the bar is on the dotted line.

I used like this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/termi1290/3z10agmm/1/)

Please suggest me some resource so that i can produce the exact copy

Following is the javascipt i am using

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100" padding-right="20px"></canvas> 
     <script>
      var data = {
        labels: ["Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat","Sun"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor: "rgba(51,190,139,1)",
                strokeColor: "rgba(51,190,139,1)",
                highlightFill: "rgba(51,190,139,1)",
                highlightStroke: "rgba(51,190,139,1)",
                data:[1000,1250,750,1160,500,1500,850],
            }
        ]
      };

      var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
      var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data,{
         responsive: true,
        barValueSpacing : 10,

      });

    </script>
```

Comment: have you tried flotr2? https://github.com/HumbleSoftware/Flotr2

Answer (score 0):

**Codepen** http://codepen.io/noobskie/pen/vNpgGe?editors=101

Are you looking for something like this?

`function(label){return  ' €' + label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");}`

This is the function you need to use to change the label and then just tweak `barValueSpacing: 40,` to whatever you need

**EDIT**

Updated codepen so now you can also mess around with the amount of labels you have on the y-axis via

```
scaleOverride : true,
scaleSteps : 10,
scaleStepWidth : 150,
scaleStartValue : 0,
```